# How to populate collection view with unique entries from core data? <obj-c>

Tags: objective-c

I have some data stored in coredata. Each row contains a entity called task id which may repeate multiple times. (I am grouping tasks according to task id.)
I want to populate the collection view with unique task id. What will be the best solution to do it.

Example:
if core data contains data as follows:
Row 1: task ID - 001 -----> and related data 
Row 2: task ID - 001 -----> and related data 
Row 3: task ID - 002 -----> and related data 
Row 4: task ID - 003 -----> and related data 
Row 5: task ID - 004 -----> and related data 
Row 6: task ID - 004 -----> and related data

Now I need to populate cells 4 cells.
Please tell me the best way to do it.
I am using some raw logic which is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller?language=objc) - there's an example there of displaying the data inside a UITableView, which would be easy to set up in your own view controller by subclassing [UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller).